# How to extend a lightweight provider in Chef

Tags: chef-infra

I am creating a bunch of different Chef providers to deploy different types of applications. Chef's documentation for [Extend a Lightweight Provider](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_lwrp_providers_extend.html) suggests it is possible but doesn't actually say what to do. That page suggests that perhaps a call to `mixin` is needed, but I don't know what structure my code should have in the file under `/libraries` or how to actually include that code in something under `/providers`.

Here are the examples of what I want to do.

In my base class under `/libraries`:

```
repository "http://my.svn.server/#{deployment[:project]}/branches/#{node[:chef_environment]}/"
user "deploy"
scm_provider Chef::Provider::Subversion
svn_username "svn_user"
svn_password "password"
```

In my provider for Torquebox Rails app deployments:

```
deploy_revision "/my/deployment/directory/#{deployment[:project]}" do
  # Magically mixin the code from libraries
  environment "RAILS_ENV" => node[:chef_environment]
  restart_command "rake torquebox:deploy"
end
```

And then of course other types of providers for different types of applications.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this? Is there documentation somewhere I'm missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Chef will [automatically convert the LWRP DSL into a full-blown Ruby class](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/provider/lwrp_base.rb#L83-L101) at runtime. This is determined by the name of the cookbook followed by the name of the file (this is the same way the actual resource name is created).

So if you have a cookbook named `bacon` and an LWRP in `bacon/resources/eat.rb`, the associated LWRP is `bacon_eat`. The associated **class** is the camel-cased, constantized version of that - `Chef::Resource::BaconEat` and `Chef::Provider::BaconEat` in this case.

There is one exception to this pattern - `default`. "Default" is special in Chef land, as it **doesn't** get prefixed. So if you have a cookbook named `bacon` and an LWRP in `bacon/resources/default.rb`, the associated LWRP is `bacon` (not `bacon_default`). The associated **class** is the camel-cased, constantized version of that - `Chef::Resource::Bacon` and `Chef::Provider::Bacon` (not "BaconDefault") in this case.

Okay, so why the backstory? In order to extend an LWRP, you want to inherit from the LWRP's class (Rubyism). So in your `libraries/` directory, you want to extend your custom resource:

```
class Chef
  class Resource::MyResource < Resource::Bacon # <- this
  end
end
```

So, in your example:

```
class Chef
  class Resource::MyDeployRevision < Resource::DeployRevision
    def initialize(name, run_context = nil)
      super

      # This is what you'll use in the recipe DSL
      @resource_name = :my_deploy_revision

      # Things like default action and parameters are inherited from the parent

      # Set your default options here
      @repository = "http://my.svn.server/#{node['deployment']['project']}/branches/#{node.chef_environment}/"
      @user = 'deploy'
      @scm_provider = Chef::Provider::Subversion
      @svn_username = 'svn_user'
      @svn_password = 'password'
    end
  end
end
```

Then use `my_deploy_revision` in your recipes.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the write up. I'll try to make some time to venture back into Chef-land again soon and try this out.

Comment: @sethvargo your answer here seems to conflict with another of your answers about [extending a LWRP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21152840/1995977), where you said it is quite difficult to extend a LWRP.  Can you clarify please?  I'm quite interested in doing this with the `simple_iptables` LWRPs...

Comment: It appears [Chef loads libraries before it loads LWRPs](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/dd742991862f6b1c9b8d193549f6b87c5c92cfa6/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb#L71). Because of this, `Resource::DeployRevision` will not have been defined yet. I found that the only way to get this to work was to put it in the `definitions/` directory since definitions are loaded after LWRPs.

Comment: Also, it looks like starting with Chef 12.4.0, you will need to use `Chef::ResourceResolver.resolve(:deploy_revision)` rather than referencing `Chef::Resource::DeployRevision` directly.  See ["LWRPs are no longer automatically placed in the Chef::Resource namespace" here](https://www.chef.io/blog/2015/06/24/chef-client-12-4-0-released/).