# Extending a Chef 12 resource (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I'm using Amazon Opsworks with Chef 12.
This comes with a built in resource called deploy (which was removed in chef 14).

My issue with *deploy* is that I need a custom release_slug

Currently the path to the release looks something like this:

/srv/www/development/releases/20180706123524

but i need my build id

/srv/www/development/releases/199

So I'm trying to extend Deploy, and replace the release_slug (20180706123524) with my custom ID.
I can see in the chef source that this is exactly what they do with their timestamped deploy: https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/12.5-stable/lib/chef/provider/deploy/timestamped.rb

I found a similar stackoverflow question here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114469/how-to-extend-a-lightweight-provider-in-chef#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114469/how-to-extend-a-lightweight-provider-in-chef#_=_)

This is what I have under /libraries in my cookbook:

**deploy_slug.rb:**

```
class Chef
    class Resource::DeploySlug < Resource::DeployRevision

        def initialize(name, run_context = nil)
            super
            @resource_name = :deploy_slug
        end
    end
end
```

Before trying to modify the release_slug, I just want the deployment to actually work using my custom resource.
And in my recipe I'm trying to call it with deploy_slug.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
* deploy_slug[/srv/www/development] action deploy
================================================================================
Error executing action `deploy` on resource 'deploy_slug[/srv/www/development]'
================================================================================
Chef::Exceptions::ProviderNotFound
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with: this is not even remotely supported. **You should not do this, it is a bad idea**. This resource was removed from Chef specifically because it's not good to use. Use a simple `git` resource instead.

That said, the issue is that you need to also subclass `Provider::Deploy::Revision` and map it to your new resource via a `provides :deploy_slug`.

Comment: Why is this such a bad idea? Doesn't the deploy resource use git in the backend, with some extra functionality like symlinking current release into the current folder?